# SSIS FlatFile Numeric cant convert to SQL bigint

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I'm making a IS task. I have a flatfile column named `SCB_ActualMIN` with a data type `string [DT_STR]`. I also have a script component to convert the `SCB_ActualMIN` column to numeric data type. I have this code in my script component

```
If Not Row.SCBActualDTime_IsNull AndAlso
              Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.SCBActualDTime.Trim) Then

        Dim dtDate As Date

        If DateTime.TryParse(Row.SCBActualDTime.Trim, dtDate) Then

            Row.OutPutColumn = dtDate

        Else

            'If column cannot be parsed

            Row.OutPutColumn_IsNull = True

        End If

    Else

        Row.OutPutColumn_IsNull = True

    End If

    '''''SCBActualDTime

    If Not Row.SCBActualMIN_IsNull AndAlso
              Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.SCBActualMIN.Trim) Then

        Dim MIN As Integer

        If Int32.TryParse(Row.SCBActualMIN.Trim, MIN) Then

            Row.OutPut2Column = MIN

        Else

            'If column cannot be parsed

            Row.OutPut2Column_IsNull = True

        End If

    Else

        Row.OutPut2Column_IsNull = True

    End If
```

As you can see the conversion of `string` to `datetime` data type is successful. While using the same code for `string` to `integer`. The `Int32.TryParse(Row.SCBActualMIN.Trim, MIN)` always return false even I have the value `09764377211` in the line code. Also is there other way for me to avoid the repetition of code.

Comment: the accepted answer is good. I posted an answer to give more details. Take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`9764377211` is bigger than `2147483647` which is the maximum value that can be assigned to `Int32`

Try converting value to `Int64` or `Double` instead of `Int32`

```
    Dim MIN As Int64

    If Int64.TryParse(Row.SCBActualMIN.Trim, MIN) Then

        Row.OutPut2Column = MIN

    Else

        'If column cannot be parsed

        Row.OutPut2Column_IsNull = True

    End If
```

OR

```
    Dim MIN As Double

    If Double.TryParse(Row.SCBActualMIN.Trim, MIN) Then

        Row.OutPut2Column = MIN

    Else

        'If column cannot be parsed

        Row.OutPut2Column_IsNull = True

    End If
```

You cannot avoid repetition because you have to check each column for null by using it is own `_IsNull` property. You can try minimizing code by creating functions.

Comment: it resulted in an error `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.`

Comment: I handled it by changing the MIN (integer) to long data type

Comment: `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow` try changing destination column data type

Comment: Yeah done that. What if I have another column that I need to convert to bigint. Do you think there is a way to reuse my code and not repeating the same code again.

Comment: You cannot avoid repetition because you have differrents data types + you have to call `_IsNull` property for input and ouptut columns. and that cannot be converted to a generic function. you have to be specific

Comment: yeah I just realized that. Its just I am concern about the speed.

Comment: This is a very simple code, even if you repeated it multiple time, it will not slow down the operation so much

Answer (score 1):

First of all, like @Yahfoufi suggested the exception is thrown because the value *"9764377211 is bigger than 2147483647 which is the maximum value that can be assigned to Int32..."*

You can Read more in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhw1f6w5(v=vs.100).aspx) about Data Types and corresponding Maximum values.

```
Type    Storage size    Range
Int32    4 bytes    -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
Int64    8 bytes    Approximately -9.2E+18 to 9.2E+18
Double   8 bytes    Approximate range is -1.79E+308 to 1.79E+308 with accuracy of about 15 digits. Can represent numbers as small as 1E-323.
Decimal  12 bytes   Approximate range is -7.9E+28 to 7.9E+28 with accuracy of 28 digits. Can represent numbers as small as 1E-28.
...
```

You can assign this value to `Int64` or `Decimal` or `Double` Data Types

**Optimizing your code**

In this case you cannot avoid the repetition of these parts of code because there are using independent properties that cannot be called dynamically:

1. Checking if Input Columns is Null or Empty

   ```
    If Not Row.SCBActualMIN_IsNull AndAlso
         Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.SCBActualMIN.Trim) Then
   ```
2. Assigning `Null`  to the output column if value cannot be parsed or input is `Null` or Empty

   ```
   Row.OutPut2Column_IsNull = True
   ```

**You can modify your code to minimize number of lines but i don't think it will improve the performance**

- For each Data Type declare one variable inside the RowProcessing Sub and make your code as the following:

*Assuming that these 2 columns are containing dates*

```
Dim dtDate As Date

If Not Row.SCBActualDTime_IsNull AndAlso
          Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.SCBActualDTime.Trim) AndAlso 
          DateTime.TryParse(Row.SCBActualDTime.Trim, dtDate)Then

        Row.OutPutColumn = dtDate

    Else

        'If column cannot be parsed or it is null

        Row.OutPutColumn_IsNull = True

    End If

'Assuming that SCBActualMIN is a Date

If Not Row.SCBActualMIN_IsNull AndAlso
          Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.SCBActualMIN.Trim) AndAlso 
          DateTime.TryParse(Row.SCBActualMIN.Trim, dtDate)Then

        Row.OutPut2Column = dtDate

    Else

        'If column cannot be parsed

        Row.OutPut2Column_IsNull = True

    End If
```

*Having a large amount of lines of code is not an issue if performance is good or optimal, Also minimizing the number of lines of code will not necessary improve the performance*

**Useful Links on SSIS , SQL , .Net Data Types**

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-and-ssis-data-types/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/data-flow/working-with-data-types-in-the-data-flow#mapping-data-types-in-the-data-flow
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types

Comment: Turns out its not on my end that has the problem. Its from who provided us the data. there is a column wih a data value `1 days , 00:35:54` and the IS accept is another column. So wtf right

Comment: Third link needs to be removed as it redirects to some weird website (looks like a SPAM)

Comment: @Naomi looks like it is no more available. I removed it